# Testing form submit not working Jest, Enzyme in react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, enzyme

I have created a react app using nextjs (react 17.02 , next 11.1.0) and going to test a simple form submit using Jest and enzyme (jest 26.4.2, enzyme 3.11.0).Test frameworks works fine. When I'm testing a form submit getting a error. I can run  the other test cases having error.

here is my signIn component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function SignIn() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
        console.log("Submit call...................");
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit} data-testid="formlogin">
                <input type="email" data-testid="emailInput" id="email-input" name="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <input type="password" data-testid="passwordInput" id="password-input" name="password" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <input data-testid="btnSignin" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the signIn.test.js file

```
import SignIn from '../components/SignIn';
import { render, shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';

describe("function test", () => {
    test("login check with right data", async () => {
        const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
        let wrapper = mount(<SignIn handleOnSubmit={handleSubmit} />);
        wrapper.find({ 'data-testid': "formlogin" }).simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => { }, });
        expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
});
```

Unfortunately when I run yarn test test is getting fail.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENDBD.png)

This test is works fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFVLh.png)

What do I need to do to solve this or can someone provide a tutorial on how to test a form submit?

Comment: Creating an `handleSubmit` mock and passing it as a prop won't work since the `handleSubmit` callback is internal to the component and not a prop. Rather than testing if `handleSubmit` gets called, you should test the result of triggering the submit event.